# Наказывается ли "сговор" на SO?

Tags: обсуждение, голосование

Скажем, коллега задал мне N вопросов в Skype, на которые я дал развёрнутые ответы. Позже я ощущаю, что вопросы качественные и могли бы укрепить базу знаний SO, так как подобные отсутствуют на нём, и поэтому прошу коллегу задать вопросы на SO.

После этого я добавляю туда свои развёрнутые ответы, а он их принимает + ставим друг другу взаимные лайки.

Считается ли это каким-то нарушением? Ведь со стороны это будет выглядеть подозрительно, как N вопросов от одного и того же юзера, который получил ответы, допустим, от меня и их принял.

Comment: По-хорошему, некрасивый тут момент только один - договорные перекрёстные лайки. Имхо более "чистым" с вашей стороны было разместить темы типа "вопрос и свой ответ на него". Ну а чтобы оба получили свою порцию восхищения,  просто договоритесь, кто какой вопрос освещает. Честно говоря, в таком подходе не вижу никаких минусов. PS. Ну или просто воздержитесь от перекрёстных лайков - если и вопрос, и ответ заслуживают, то в выхлопе эти баллы просто потеряются.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Отвечать на вопросы коллеги - нормально и даже хорошо.
- Голосовать друг другу за ответы/вопросы - не так хорошо.

Так что, отвечая на вопрос, наказывается целенаправленное голосование за/против одного пользователя.

Такие голоса обычно откатываются системой автоматически. В некоторых случаях нам (модераторам) приходится вмешиваться самим.

До тех пор, пока вы не нарушаете правил по голосованию, всё нормально.

Comment: А как работает система? Ну скажем, если не злоупотреблять, а умеренно время от времени лайкать.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы сейчас, по сути, спрашиваете у модератора о том, как можно обмануть систему? :D

Comment: Да, со стороны похоже на то =DD Ладно, забыли.

Comment: А принимать то ответы не возбраняется? Ограничение только на лайки?

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, принимать можно.

Comment: В справке я нашёл следующее: _"преднамеренное голосование с единственной целью повышения либо понижения репутации другого пользователя считается нарушением."_. Но я не до конца понимаю, что значит _"с единственной целью"_. Допустимо ли всё таки взаимное голосование, если оно происходит нечасто и исключительно из благих намерений (пополнить базу знаний качественными ответами)? Я не прошу разъяснять мне систему, мне больше интересно отношение сообщества (модераторов в частности), это считается нормальным или нет? Если упростить: "Мы поддерживаем такое поведение или возбраняем?".

Comment: @nomnoms12 усердно голосовать целенаправленно за конкретных участников не приветствуется, скажем так. Может быть расценено как накрутка. Где граница? Не могу сказать. Такие случаи обычно рассматриваются индивидуально.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Спасибо за ответ! В принципе, всё ясно, "грязная" получается репутация. Одно знаю точно — у нас прекрасный модераторский состав, и если такие случаи всё таки будут, вынесется адекватное решение :)

Comment: Ромбовый модератор высказался вполне понятно. Я бы только хотел добавить своё скромное мнение, что ситуация должна рассматриваться с позиции пользы для сообщества в целом. От хороших вопросов и ответов все в выигрыше. Будут ли они оформлены как решение своего же вопроса или в виде диалога, это уже вторично. Я думаю, в большинстве случаев модераторы адекватно оценивают значимость темы.